# Update data in Vue.js Mounted() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I try to update some data in my mounted part, in my Vue.js component. Here is my code :

```
  methods: {
    initData() {
      const self = this;

      axios
        .get("/checkAuthentification")
        .then((response) => {
          (self.userFields.userAuthenticated = response.data),
            console.log("method"),
            console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated),
            console.log("reponse"),
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          (self.errors = error.response.data.errors || {}),
            console.log(self.errors);
        });

      console.log("between");

      console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated);

      if (self.userFields.userAuthenticated == "true") {
        axios
          .get("/getAuthenticatedUserData")
          .then((response) => {
            (self.userId = String(response.data.id)),
              (self.userFields = response.data),
              console.log("user data"),
              console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            (self.errors = error.response.data.errors || {}),
              console.log(self.errors);
          });
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initData();
  },
```

In the first axios call, it works perfectly, the two console log give the expected value "true". But on the next console.log after between, it says 'undefined'. Thue userFields doesn't update after the firt axios call. I don't understand because i did the same thing on a submit button on a form, and it worked perfectly.
I ask here because I looked other posts and the answer is always to use const=this, which I did.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Did you try or check async/await ? I think you need to wait until the first axios process finishes because it is asynchronous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions first you would have to understand the nature of asynchronous operations in Javascript. I will try my best to explain but will leave this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) in case you would like to read more about it

On your example you have:

```
axios.get('/checkAuthentification').then(response =>{
  console.log('CHecked authentication')
  ...
})

console.log('between');

console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated);
```

When you do the `axios.get` what happens is that an asynchornous operation will be called (asynchornous = won't wait for the answer for the code to continue execution). You will contact your backend server and ONLY when you receive an answer the `console.log('checked authentication')` will run but in the meantime (remember `axios.get` is asynchronous) the `console.log('between'); AND console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated);` will execute before you receive an answer from the backend server.

**How can we solve this**
We can solve this with two approaches. The first one would be the more old approach - waiting for promises to resolve by the `then` keyword

```
axios
  .get('/checkAuthentification')
  .then(response =>{
    console.log('CHecked authentication')
  
    console.log('between');

    console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated);
    
    return response;
  })
  .then(() => {
    // do more operations after promise was resolved
  })
```

Or we can do a more modern way - we can use async/await.

```
async initData() {
  const response = await axios.get('/checkAuthentification');

  console.log('CHecked authentication')
  
  console.log('between');

  console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot ! I worked. I will definitely take the time to read more about asynchronous operations; because I will work a lot with axios so it will be useful. 
If I understood well, will it work if I symply separate each axios call in a dedicated function in methods, and then call them one by one ? Will the functions wait correctly ?

Comment: It's hard to tell you ithout an example. Feel free to update the question to include the example and then I can help you out.

Comment: @PierreCsts if this answer answered your question, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

```js
 state: {
   userFields: {
     userAuthenticated: false,
     ...
   }
 },
  methods: {
    initData() {
      const self = this;

      axios
        .get("/checkAuthentification")
        .then((response) => {
          (self.userFields.userAuthenticated = response.data),
            console.log("method"),
            console.log(self.userFields.userAuthenticated),
            console.log("reponse"),
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          (self.errors = error.response.data.errors || {}),
            console.log(self.errors);
        });

    },
    getUserData() {
      if (this.userFields.userAuthenticated) {
        axios
          .get("/getAuthenticatedUserData")
          .then((response) => {
            (self.userId = String(response.data.id)),
              (self.userFields = response.data),
              console.log("user data"),
              console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            (self.errors = error.response.data.errors || {}),
              console.log(self.errors);
          });
      }

    }
  },
  watch: {
    'userFields.userAuthenticated': function() {
       this.getUserData()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initData();
  },
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code for better understanding.